# How could I test my application services in test project?

Tags: .net-core, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

When I try to run my test case I am getiing this exception:
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'Castle.Core.Pair`2' from assembly 'Castle.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc'.

My aspnetboilerplate version: 7.3.0, Aspnet Core MVC.

I have added app.config file into Test project and defined assemblyBinding. However, It doesn't solve the issue.

There is a link about the solution in abp.io community site but the link is not working.